# Chart in Ionic Framework doesn't show up

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, chart.js

i'm trying to create a chart in my Ionic App using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/), when i add the required code to the app and test it in the desktop, the chart apears correctly but when i build the app and test it in the phone the whole page where is supposed to be the chart goes blank and doesn't show anything.

I tried with another angular plugin to create charts but had the same result, both of them uses [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)

Do you know another angular-chart framework that works with Ionic? or have any idea of what the problem could be?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Can you share your code that you have tried?

Comment: Have you checked the sample project in github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you include the style sheet's  in Ionic framework will have the drawback to display the charts in simulator or in mobile device. I am uploading a sample project on Charts by using Ionic framework in [github](https://github.com/anilkumar007/Charts).
1.Please follow the steps in readme.md file of github 
2.Download the required files to run the project 
3.Having any queries please reply

I think the drawback for your project is the way of css file's you include

I followed like this

```
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: For reference please see this [link](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/08/using-charts-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/)

Comment: Thanks anil, i checked the project in github and it helped me to find out that the problem wasn't the angular-chart.js framework, i was having a routing issue (Still don't know what) but i added $state.go to go to the section where the charts are and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[I also had issues on android](https://github.com/saurabhgupta050890/ionic-chart-example/issues/2) with Charts.js/angles.js, when testing using [another useful set of ionic chart examples on github](https://github.com/saurabhgupta050890/ionic-chart-example). [Angular-nvD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/), [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) or [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en) may be better options.